# customized ,manipulate textbox ( how to modify it's apparence )

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo

does anybody has a clue on how to make a custum textbox like component that act quite like the email field used on facebook or hotmail when sending messages.

the main function of this textbox is that it separate autamaticly the emails or the friend names and transform them into a rectangle with a tiny x to remove the item if the user had make some mistake .

i dont think that this component is already included into the Dojo ToolKit ,i'm aiming to create one but i'm having trouble to find the functions and methods needed to apply these kind of effects on a textbox .
i'm not asking for specific functions or methods , i thinks that textbox is represented ans manipulated like any DOM element ,please don't hesitate to make any suggestion !

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

What you describe sounds kind of like `dojox.form.ListInput`, though that one seems a bit unpolished.  Might be worth a look though.

http://www.dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/form/ListInput.html

http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/form/tests/test_ListInput.html

Comment: thanks, that quite what i was looking for ,but the dojo implementation of this component is'nt stable and lacks of documentation ...
any way thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

for whom are intressted i found a thread where this subject is involved with many examples :

http://ajaxian.com/archives/facebook-style-input-box